# Top selling product per user_id and categorize by each user's buying activity (first-time, second-time, etc.)

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I'm working on MySQL workbench and I would like to find the top-selling products by types of buyers. First I categorized customers based on their buying activity. If a person made a purchase only on 1/1, it's a first-time buyer. If a person made a purchase on 1/1 and 1/2, it's a second-time buyer. If a person made a purchase on 1/1, 1/2, and 1/3, it's a third-time buyer. And so on.

The following is sample data, similar to my original data.

| user_id | PurchaseDate | Product | Total | order_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 16:46 | yogurt | 3.72 | 1000 |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 18:23 | milk | 4.38 | null |
| 2 | 2023-01-01 12:34 | egg | 4.57 | 1001 |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 11:54 | butter | 3.69 | null |
| 3 | 2023-01-01 10:41 | cheese | 3.68 | 1003 |
| 2 | 2023-01-01 13:45 | milk | 4.38 | null |
| 3 | 2023-01-03 18:56 | yogurt | 3.72 | 1005 |
| 3 | 2023-01-02 19:12 | cream | 4.98 | 1004 |
| 2 | 2023-01-02 12:47 | egg | 4.57 | 1002 |

If a customer makes more than one purchase on the same date, the order_id is null.
So, I used that to categorize the buyers.

```
SELECT      user_id, product, sum(Total) as Total,
            CASE WHEN Count(DISTINCT(order_id)) = 1 THEN "FirstTimeBuyer" 
                 WHEN Count(DISTINCT(order_id)) = 2 THEN "SecondTimeBuyer" 
                 WHEN Count(DISTINCT(order_id)) = 3 THEN "ThirdTimeBuyer"
                 END AS TypeofBuyer
FROM    myData
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY Total DESC;
```

And I get the following result

| user_id | Product | Total | TypeofBuyer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | egg | 13.52 | SecondTimeBuyer |
| 3 | cheese | 12.38 | ThirdTimeBuyer |
| 1 | yogurt | 11.79 | FirstTimeBuyer |

But the problem is since I aggregated the total and grouped it by user_id, I cannot find the top-selling product for each user_id.

For instance, for user_id 1, the top-selling product is milk and the customer is a first-time buyer.

How can I extract the above information?

I'd appreciate your help!

Edit: Eventually, I'm aiming to visualize the top 10 selling products for 1st-time buyers, 2nd-time buyers, and so forth (my original data is much bigger than the sample)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
/*first cte*/
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT user_id, Product, Total,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY Total DESC) Rnum,
       SUM(Total) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id) AS GTotal,
       order_id
FROM myData),
/*second cte*/
  cte2 AS (
SELECT user_id,
       CASE WHEN Count(DISTINCT(order_id)) = 1 THEN "FirstTimeBuyer" 
                 WHEN Count(DISTINCT(order_id)) = 2 THEN "SecondTimeBuyer" 
                 WHEN Count(DISTINCT(order_id)) = 3 THEN "ThirdTimeBuyer"
                 END AS TypeofBuyer
 FROM cte
  GROUP BY user_id)
/*join the ctes*/
SELECT cte.user_id, cte.Product, cte.Total, cte.GTotal, cte2.TypeofBuyer
   FROM cte 
   JOIN cte2 ON cte.user_id=cte2.user_id
WHERE Rnum=1
ORDER BY GTotal DESC;
```

Using `ROW_NUMBER()` to get top sales and assign with row numbering and `SUM() OVER ()` to get total sales by `user_id` in the first `cte`. Then re-using your method of getting `TypeofBuyer` in the second `cte`. Lastly, a query to join both of the `ctes` and filter only rows with row number=1 to get your desired result.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/s2DA0Vou)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CTE.

```
With FavouriteProduct as
(
select user_id, 
Product As FavouriteProduct, 
count(Product) as BuyCount, 
sum(total) as TotalSpentFavourite 
From dbo.myData
group by user_id, Product
),

UserTotals as
(
select user_id, 
sum(total) as TotalSpent,
CASE 
    WHEN Count(DISTINCT(order_id)) = 1 THEN 'FirstTimeBuyer'
    WHEN Count(DISTINCT(order_id)) = 2 THEN 'SecondTimeBuyer' 
    WHEN Count(DISTINCT(order_id)) = 3 THEN 'ThirdTimeBuyer'
END AS TypeofBuyer
From dbo.myData
group by user_id
)

select DISTINCT  D.user_id, 
TypeofBuyer,
TotalSpent,
FP.FavouriteProduct,
FP.TotalSpentFavourite 
From dbo.myData D
outer apply
(
select top 1 * from FavouriteProduct FP where fp.user_id = D.user_id order by BuyCount desc
) FP
inner join UserTotals on UserTotals.user_id = D.user_id
order by user_id
```

Output:

| user_id | TypeofBuyer | FavouriteProduct | TotalSpent | TotalSpentFavourite |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | FirstTimeBuyer | milk | 11.79 | 4.38 |
| 2 | SecondTimeBuyer | egg | 13.52 | 9.14 |
| 3 | ThirdTimeBuyer | cream | 12.38 | 4.98 |

Comment: The question is tagged as `mysql` so you would need to change `TOP` to a `LIMIT` clause, and change `OUTER APPLY` to `LEFT JOIN LATERAL` or move it to a correlated subquery in the `SELECT` list, as it is only returning a single value.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specify which mysql version you are using, it's possible you're using a sub-8.0 one, in which window functions such as CTE are not supported. Therefore, I'm taking a version-neutral approach. 
First of all, let's get the top-selling product for each user_id.

```
select t1.user_id,t2.product
from
    (select user_id,max(sm) mx
    from
        (select user_id,product,sum(total) sm
        from mydata
        group by user_id,product) t
    group by user_id) t1
join
    (select user_id,product,sum(total) sm
    from mydata
    group by user_id,product) t2
on t1.user_id=t2.user_id and mx=sm
;

-- result set:
| user_id | product |
+---------+---------+
|       1 | milk    |
|       2 | egg     |
|       3 | cream   |
+---------+---------+
```

The rest is to join the previous query to your query.

```
select ta.user_id, tb.product, ta.Total, ta.TypeofBuyer
from
    (SELECT      user_id, sum(Total) as Total,
            CASE WHEN Count(DISTINCT(order_id)) = 1 THEN "FirstTimeBuyer" 
                 WHEN Count(DISTINCT(order_id)) = 2 THEN "SecondTimeBuyer" 
                 WHEN Count(DISTINCT(order_id)) = 3 THEN "ThirdTimeBuyer"
                 END AS TypeofBuyer
    FROM    myData
    GROUP BY user_id) ta
join
    (select t1.user_id,t2.product
    from
        (select user_id,max(sm) mx
        from
            (select user_id,product,sum(total) sm
            from mydata
            group by user_id,product) t
        group by user_id) t1
    join
        (select user_id,product,sum(total) sm
        from mydata
        group by user_id,product) t2
    on t1.user_id=t2.user_id and mx=sm
    ) tb
on ta.user_id=tb.user_id
;
-- result set:
| user_id | product | Total | TypeofBuyer     |
+---------+---------+-------+-----------------+
|       1 | milk    | 11.79 | FirstTimeBuyer  |
|       2 | egg     | 13.52 | SecondTimeBuyer |
|       3 | cream   | 12.38 | ThirdTimeBuyer  |
+---------+---------+-------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current CASE operation is doing more work than it needs to:

```
CASE WHEN Count(DISTINCT(order_id)) = 1 THEN "FirstTimeBuyer" 
     WHEN Count(DISTINCT(order_id)) = 2 THEN "SecondTimeBuyer" 
     WHEN Count(DISTINCT(order_id)) = 3 THEN "ThirdTimeBuyer"
     END AS TypeofBuyer
```

Internally, this will require a separate temporary table for each [`COUNT(DISTINCT)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/internal-temporary-tables.html#:%7E:text=Evaluation%20of%20GROUP_CONCAT()%20or%20COUNT(DISTINCT)%20expressions), even though it is essentially comparing the same value. Rewriting it like:

```
CASE COUNT(DISTINCT(order_id))
    WHEN 1 THEN "FirstTimeBuyer" 
    WHEN 2 THEN "SecondTimeBuyer" 
    WHEN 3 THEN "ThirdTimeBuyer"
END AS TypeofBuyer
```

requires only one temporary table to evaluate the three cases. It is not a significant overhead, but why do more work than is necessary?

The *"removal"* of the `order_id`s, for subsequent orders on the same day, breaks your relational model and I do not understand the intent. If it is just for the sake of calculating your `TypeofBuyer`, then perhaps `COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(PurchaseDate))` is a better option.

Yet another way to retrieve the `top-selling product` is with a correlated subquery. As with many things in the SQL world, there are many ways to achieve the same end goal, and you should test with a real world representative dataset to see what works best with your data:

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    (
        SELECT Product
        FROM myData
        WHERE user_id = md.user_id
        GROUP BY Product
        ORDER BY SUM(Total) DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS Product,
    SUM(Total) AS Total,
    CASE COUNT(DISTINCT(DATE(PurchaseDate)))
        WHEN 1 THEN 'FirstTimeBuyer' 
        WHEN 2 THEN 'SecondTimeBuyer' 
        WHEN 3 THEN 'ThirdTimeBuyer'
        ELSE 'SuperBuyer'
    END AS TypeofBuyer
FROM myData md
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY Total DESC;
```

Output:

| user_id | Product | Total | TypeofBuyer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | egg | 13.52 | SecondTimeBuyer |
| 3 | cream | 12.38 | ThirdTimeBuyer |
| 1 | milk | 11.79 | FirstTimeBuyer |

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hRiibsqH)